# Failed to construct Notification: Illegal constructor

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, mobile, html5-notifications

My site uses desktop notifications which have never worked on mobile devices but I've recently started to receive the following exception in Chrome Version 42.0.2311.108 on Android 4.4:

```
Failed to construct 'Notification': Illegal constructor. Use ServiceWorkerRegistration.showNotification() instead. TypeError: Failed to construct 'Notification': Illegal constructor. Use ServiceWorkerRegistration.showNotification() instead.
```

My notification code is simple, after checking if the user has granted permissions I initialize a new Notification object as follows:

```
var notification = new Notification(messageOptions.title, { icon: messageOptions.icon });
```

How do I change this code to use the ServiceWorkerRegistration.showNotification, which comes up as `undefined`, to support notifications in the mobile version of Chrome or if that isn't possible do a feature detection and prevent the exceptions from happening if this really isn't supported [yet].

Comment: I just put this together, does this work for you? http://jsbin.com/rexede/latest/quiet/

Comment: Same error message for your example. Works fine on desktop chrome but fails on android. Chrome 42.0.2311.109 on Android 5.1.0; Nexus 5 Build/LMY47I

Answer (score 30):

See [crbug.com/481856](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=481856) on the Chrome issue tracker:

> `new Notification()` is [on the path to deprecation](https://github.com/whatwg/notifications/issues/26), because it implicitly assumes that the page will outlive the notification, which is very unlikely on mobile (and far from guaranteed on desktop too).
>
> Hence we will never implement it on Android. We might one day remove it on desktop too, after a deprecation period.
>
> Websites should use `ServiceWorkerRegistration.showNotification()` ([see spec](https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/#service-worker-api)) instead whenever it is available.
>
> The best way I can think of to feature-detect `new Notification()` is to try it (*before* you have permission) and catch the error:
>
> ```
> function isNewNotificationSupported() {
>     if (!window.Notification || !Notification.requestPermission)
>         return false;
>     if (Notification.permission == 'granted')
>         throw new Error('You must only call this *before* calling Notification.requestPermission(), otherwise this feature detect would bug the user with an actual notification!');
>     try {
>         new Notification('');
>     } catch (e) {
>         if (e.name == 'TypeError')
>             return false;
>     }
>     return true;
> }
> ```
>
> You could then use it like this:
>
> ```
> if (window.Notification && Notification.permission == 'granted') {
>     // We would only have prompted the user for permission if new
>     // Notification was supported (see below), so assume it is supported.
>     doStuffThatUsesNewNotification();
> } else if (isNewNotificationSupported()) {
>     // new Notification is supported, so prompt the user for permission.
>     showOptInUIForNotifications();
> }
> ```

Comment: Note that the linked Chrome issue has been [updated](https://github.com/whatwg/notifications/issues/26#issuecomment-126310459) in the meantime and now says `It seems we're keeping non-persistent notifications.`

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/onnotificationclick):

> `Note`: Trying to create a notification inside the ServiceWorkerGlobalScope using the Notification() constructor will throw an error.

If you want to send notification in a Service Worker, use `self.registration.showNotification()`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification